# Overriding get method in class based view with super()

Tags: python, django, django-class-based-views, overriding

I created a view that manages the products which belong to the current log-in user (so the current user can watch its own products):

```
class ProductList(View):
  def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    products = Product.objects.get(user=self.request.user)
    #...
```

I would like to subclass another view from it, which manages the products that belong to a user specified as a GET parameter in the url (probably different to the current user). Is it possible to do it with super() and overriding the method in product_list? Something like this:

```
class ProductListFromUser(ProductList):
   def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
     #not sure what code if necessary to put here...
     super().get(self, request, *args, **kwargs): 
     #or here
#...
```

Basically, how can I override the get method from product_list , changing only "self.request.user" by the parameter taken from the URL

Comment: Welcome to SO. It would be a good idea to follow name conventios for your classes, wich is `CamelCase`. So instead of `product_list` and `product_list_from_user`, `ProductList` and `ProductListFromUser`. Lower case is for methods.

Comment: Without the "_" between.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't do either of these.

If you have a view that renders a list of items, you should use a subclass of ListView. In that view, you can define the product list in the `get_queryset` method, which you can define in the relevant way in your two different views.

```
class ProductList(ListView):
  def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
    return Product.objects.filter(user=self.request.user)

class ProductListFromUser(ListView):
  def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
    return Product.objects.filter(user__username=self.request.GET['user'])
```

You should rarely need to define `get` (or `post`) directly in a class-based view.

Answer (score 2):

I would move the retrieval of the appropriate QuerySet to an extra method which you can override in order to reuse as much of the initial code as possible:

```
class ProductList(View):

    def get_products(self):
        return Product.objects.all()

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        products = self.get_products()
        # ... 

class ProductList(View):

    def get_products(self):
        qs = super().get_products()
        qs = qs.filter(user=self.request.user)
        return qs

    # no get needed
```

This very functionality comes with django's `ListView` and its `get_queryset` method.

Answer (score 0):

If you retrieve the queryset for a given request using the get_queryset method, that CBV such as DetailView use, then you can simply override the get_queryset of the parent-class.